# EXTJS changing Grid cell back ground color on click

Tags: javascript, extjs4

Portion of my code

```
xtype: 'grid',

width: 500,
store: store6,

columns:[{

text:'Market',

sortable: false,

width:145,
dataIndex: 'market
}]
```

I've tried using listeners(which I think i didn't do correctly) and I don't know if click will work here due to each cell not having an id tag.

USE CASE
1. User clicks cell
2. Code turns cell green
3. User clicks the same cell
4. Code turns cell white
The color to each cell depends solely from the user.

This is all client side development which I haven't started any server side (PHP) development yet. I've searched on Stack for a bit and I haven't found a solution that works. Any help or comments would really help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank InnerJL for directing me in the right direction. I needed it to work for click. Alternating between white and green. Solution is posted below

```
function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store)
{
var test =  Ext.get(metaData.id).getStyle("background-color");
if(test == "green")
{
Ext.get(metaData.id).setStyle("background-color", "white");
}
else
{
Ext.get(metaData.id).setStyle("background-color", "green");
}
return value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did similar things and we used custom [column renderer](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer).

Here it's code for example:

```
statusRenderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
        if (rowIndex == undefined) {
            return;
        }
        metaData.css = getCss(value);
        return formatValue(value);
    }
```

Note that you could modify the css  property in metadata - you could setup color of the cell. For example on each click you increment some internal counter of your record. Then you renderer depending on this counter adds different css classes on the cell.

Hope this helps!

Comment: ok I'll this a shot. This is a good time to get into metadata because I don't know much about it but I'll let you know if this solves my problem.

Comment: Would you have to get a listener started first?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the statusRenederer and nothing happens but I"m getting some response from the code below.

```
fn:function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store)
{
alert(metaData.id);
metaData.trattr = 'style="background-color: red;"';
alert(metaData.css);
return value;
}
```

The thing is that I can actually get the id. Also getCSS also had some problems. Unless there is an ExtJS class that I can't look up on sencha.com. I can get the ID just fine but no way to change the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

SUCCESS!!!!

```
fn:function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store)
{
document.getElementById(metaData.id).style.background = "green";
return value;
}
```

I went to DOM programming instead of looking through ExtJS which is what I really would have preferred but this gets the job done. All I have to do is toggle between green and white.